# Get the number of affected rows in SQLJ update statement

Tags: java, sql, db2, sqlj

I am executing an update statement through SQLJ:

```
#sql [connCtx] {
    UPDATE
        MYTABLE 
    SET
        MYCOLUMN = null
    WHERE
       MYCOLUMN IS NOT NULL
};
```

Is there a way to retrieve the number of affected rows?

Comment: could you post the regarding java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without having your java code I think that is the correct way:

```
System.out.println(exec_context.getUpdateCount( ));
```

Comment: +1, Its there: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/tjvsjxcn.htm